# Get the parent folder of a file

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using [CreateFileActivityBuilder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/CreateFileActivityBuilder.html) to create a file. I want to create a second file in the same directory of the first file (without using CreateFileActivityBuilder()). How can I get the parent folder of a file if I have the DriveId of the file?

Comment: Please post a link that actually works.

Comment: So you are creating a file in the cloud. In google drive?